# When given a sentence, how to create a border for every single word including whitespace through iteration in react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to create a border for each word in a sentence including white space in a fixed frame. So for instance when given sentence such as "I like learning code", I want 4 rows since there are 4 words in a sentence and border for each word and white space just like image below. Grey box for a word and orange box for white space. So top row refers to "I ",therefore 1 grey box and orange box then "like " equals to 4 grey boxes followed by orange box and so on.
Challenge I'm facing is when I use sentence.split("").map, I will get more than 10 rows, since each character is mapped. When I use sentence.split(" ").map, I get 4 rows which is good, but I was able to only create a border on first character of each word. I'm guessing I need to find a way to split the sentence into something like this ["I ","like ", "learning ", "code"] where I include a white space along with word? Any guidance would be appreciated. Here is the link for code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-sun-3u7b3?file=/src/App.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  let sentence = "I like learning code";

  return (
    <div>
      {sentence.split(" ").map((letter, i) => (
        <p className="letterBorder" key={i}>
          {letter}
        </p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.letterBorder {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #2980b9;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0 3px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 20px;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just split on whitespaces to get every row. On each row you would need to split each letter, and add a whitespace at the end. Something like this:

```
function App() {
  let sentence = "I like learning code";
  const words = sentence.split(" ");

  return (
    <div>
      {
        words.map((word, i) => (
        <div className="row" key={i}>
          {
            [...word].map(letter=> (
              <p className="letterBorder">
                {letter}
              </p>
            ))
          }
          {
            i === words.length-1 ? null : <p className="whitespaceBorder"></p>
          }
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then you can style everything with css.

You can see a working sample [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-leftpad-c5qcc?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: This almost works! Except I don't need white space border after last word "code" as there is no white space after. Maybe I can use conditional css for that. Thanks!

Comment: I realized that after I posted the answer, I just updated it. It should work now